# VS2015 compile errors with Win API GetIscsiSessionList of Iscsidsc.h

Tags: visual-studio, api, compiler-errors

I want to user a Windows API called GetIscsiSessionList to get the information of session list.

I came across with a compile problem, VS2015 complains as follows:

VS complians of GetIscsiSessionList:

[image: VS complians of GetIscsiSessionList]

VS complians in header file Iscsidsc.h:

[image: VS complians in header file Iscsidsc.h]

Iscsidsc.h is in C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um 
. Since Iscsidsc.h is a Windows provided file, I don't understand why VS compiler will complain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order of include header files should be as follows:

iscsierr.h should be in front of iscsidsc.h